# Identity framework - how to join another profile table by UserID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have set Identity so I have separate table for user profile data (*firstname, lastname etc.*).
Problem is that I have joined those tables via `Email` field.
I want to change this so I can connect tables by `UserID` instead.
What I need is to get new `userID` for created user and use that as foreign key to `UserProfileInfo` object.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfileInfo UserProfileInfo { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfileInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

When I create new user I have:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser()
{
    UserName = model.UserName,
    Email = model.Email,
    ConfirmationToken = confirmationToken,
    IsConfirmed = false,
    UserProfileInfo = new UserProfileInfo { EmailId = model.Email }
};

var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    SendEmailConfirmation(model.Email, model.UserName, confirmationToken);
    return RedirectToAction("RegisterStepTwo", "Account");
}
else...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you doing a join in the first place? `ApplicationUser` *is* your user, and the whole point of inheriting from `IdentityUser` is to allow you extend the user object. Just put your properties like `FirstName` and `LastName` directly on `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: To separate `account` data from `profile` data. Is it bad practice to put all in one table? I can have up to 15 more columns in ApplicationUser then.

Comment: There's no reason to separate account data and profile data and it's not bad practice to have it all in one table. Still pray attention to normalization though; if it's a piece of data that is not applicable to every user (like an auth token for Facebook), it should be a claim rather than a property on `ApplicationUser`.